# Parse string with integer value to date

Tags: java, parsing, date

I have a string with this value, for example: "20130211154717" I want it to be like "2013-02-11 15:47:17". How can I do that?

Comment: string.substring + concatenation.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc. We should operate on Date string as Date only.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Possibly this is the quickest way, if the string is well formed and the date is correct. `DateFormat` can ensure the validity of a string to try to convert to `Date`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use two [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html): one to parse the input and one to produce the output:

```
String input =  "20130211154717";
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss").parse(input);
String output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(d);
System.out.println("output = " + output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions for that:

```
String formattedDate = plainDate.replaceFirst(
        "(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})",
        "$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6");
```

Though, I like assylias's `SimpleDateFormat` answer better. :-)

Comment: Totally, right? That's why I said I liked the `SimpleDateFormat` approach better. :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use for this is a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).  It has a method called [parse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `substring()` method to get what you want:

```
String data = "20130211154717";
String year = data.substring(0, 4);
String month = data.substring(4, 2);
// etc.
```

and then string them together:

```
String formatted = year + "-" + month + "-" + . . .
```