# How can I convert an Integer (e.g 19000101 ) to java.util.Date?

Tags: java, date, integer, data-conversion

Here's my code:

```
Integer value = 19000101;
```

How can I convert the above `Integer` represented in `YYYYMMDD` format to `YYYY-MM-DD` format in  `java.util.Date`?

Comment: what does that number represent? Is it time, or some format?

Comment: have you tried Date formatter?

Comment: this number is in YYYYMMDD format. I need YYYY-MM-DD format

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse string with integer value to date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817898/parse-string-with-integer-value-to-date)

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.util.Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First you have to parse your format into date object using formatter specified

```
Integer value = 19000101;
SimpleDateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Date date = originalFormat.parse(value.toString());
```

Remember that Date has no format. It just represents specific instance in time in milliseconds starting from 1970-01-01. But if you want to format that date to your expected format, you can use another formatter.

```
SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String formatedDate = newFormat.format(date);
```

Now your `formatedDate` String should contain string that represent date in format `yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: not working for me .my code is : 

DateTimeFormatter formatter=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYYMMdd");
String date="20200913T12:00:00+0000".substring(0, 8).trim();
System.out.println("=======given date ====="+date);

Comment: your format is not correct. Format is case sensitive. you need to use `yyyyMMdd`

Comment: @TariqAbbas For that string please see [Java String to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18823627/java-string-to-datetime).

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that you don't really have a *number* representing your date, you have a string of three numbers: year, month, and day. You can extract those values with some simple arithmetic.

```
Integer value = 19000101;
int year = value / 10000;
int month = (value % 10000) / 100;
int day = value % 100;
Date date = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day).getTime();
```

Comment: I got `Thu Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1900`. I don’t think February was intended. It’s how confusing the `GregorianCalendar` class is. I recommend we don’t use it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String myDate= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                          .format(new Date(19000101 * 1000L));
```

Assuming it is the time since 1/1/1970

**EDIT:-**

If you want to convert from YYYYMMDD to YYYY-MM-DD format

```
Date dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(String.ValueOf(19000101));
```

Comment: Not quite right, because `parse` takes a string.  Otherwise, this answer has the right idea.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for all of your date work.

I am assuming that you want January 1, 1900 from your integer value, 19000101. With java.time that’s a one-liner.

```
    Integer value = 19000101;
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(
            value.toString(), DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);
    System.out.println(date);
```

Output:

> 1900-01-01

I am exploiting the fact that your format agrees with the basic ISO 8601 format for a date. There is a built-in formatter for this format. Which is very good news since writing our own format pattern strings is always error-prone.

### I said java.util.Date

If you indispensably need an old-fashioned `java.util.Date`, typically for a legacy API not yet upgraded to java.time, the conversion is:

```
    Instant startOfDay = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
    Date oldfashionedDate = Date.from(startOfDay);
    System.out.println(oldfashionedDate);
```

Example output:

> Mon Jan 01 00:21:00 EET 1900

(The 21 minutes are due to a bug in the `Date` class. Such bugs exist for dates close to year 1900.)

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Java versions and on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

First, the value you provided should be long, then just do as follow:

```
Date date = new Date(19000101L);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy", new Locale(<language>, <country>));
```

The default for Locale is English, so you can just ignore it.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Also I’m convinced that the OP expected 1 Jan 1900. From your code I got 1 Jan 1970, so 70 years off.