# I want to convert Time in seconds to day hour minute and second in Java

Tags: java, simpledateformat

For example I want convert 283392s to 3d 6h 43m 12s. Can this be achieved with SimpleDateFormat ?

Comment: this can be achieved by simple logic

Comment: Yes you can. Check the documents or search for it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25458832/how-can-i-convert-an-integer-e-g-19000101-to-java-util-date

Comment: Is 2833.... in seconds?

Comment: I have already achieved this using maths but  i am looking for some simple solution.

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný yes its in seconds.

Comment: No you should not do it with `SimpleDateFormat` or any other formatter which is designed to format points in time. What you need is a formatter capable of formatting ELAPSED time. Either you study external library solutions (like in Joda-Time or my lib Time4J), or you apply your own work-around (see TimeUnit-answer below).

Answer (score 0):

In java 8 you can do the following one-liner:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
System.out.println(LocalTime.MIN.plusSeconds(283392).toString());
```

That returns "6:43:12"

Answer (score 0):

It should easily be done using TimeUnit like so:

```
 int day = (int)TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(seconds);        
 long hours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds) - (day *24);
 long minute = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds) - (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds)* 60);
 long second = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(seconds) - (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds) *60);
```