# Checking digits in string, doesnt work when the string starts with a 0

Tags: java, while-loop, int, string-length, value-of

I have a homework assignment where we have to make a very basic console app for a fitness center, that can create members and employees. My problem occurs when i ask the user to type in the birthday of the new members. It is supposed to check if the birthday is in the format DD/MM/YY, so i check if the answer given is 6 digits, and 6 digits only. And it seems to work, unless someone gives a birth date that start with 0, EG.: 090498.

```
System.out.println("Please enter the new members birthday, in the format of DD/MM/YY:");
    this.birthdate = console1.nextInt();
    while(String.valueOf(birthdate).length() != 6){
    System.out.println("Please give a valid date of birth in the format of: DD/MM/YY");
    this.birthdate = console1.nextInt();
}
```

It doesn't give a error message, but only completes the loop if the birthdate IS 6 digits, AND starts with a 1 EG.: 190798.

i know this is probably very simple, but i only started studying CS about a month ago :)

Comment: Yes, because you are accepting an int, and the initial 0 is dropped automatically. You should accept a string.

Comment: Date formats like `DD/MM/YY` are not a single number but a combination of 3 numbers so if you want to have the date entered as one you need to use a string. This could then be checked with a regex to only allow valid numbers for each part. In contrast your method would allow me to enter a date of 999999 and this would be considered valid because it is a 6-digit number.

Comment: A regex to check for plausible date input could be `^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[0-2])[0-9]{2}$`. This would alloww days in the range 01-31 and months in the range 01-12 but it would allow "invalid" dates like Feb 30th or April 31st so you'd either need a more complex one or - which I'd say would be way better - properly parse the input into a `Date` or at least into 3 integers which you then could feed to more thorough checks.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers told you if you start an int with 0 the code will ignore it. You can import a SimpleDate and with a String you can use it. I leave here a link on another question that maybe can help you more.
[link] [How can I convert an Integer (e.g 19000101 ) to java.util.Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25458832/how-can-i-convert-an-integer-e-g-19000101-to-java-util-date)

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
import java.util.Date; 

public class StringToDateEXE {  
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {  
    String DateT="31/12/1998";  
    Date NDate=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(DateT);  
    System.out.println(DateT+"\t"+NDate);  
}  
}
```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are accepting an int, and the initial 0 is automatically dropped. And a birthday should not be represented as an integer. My advice is to change that field as a String, and accepting a value of that type as a consequence.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking an `int` and that makes it drop the leading 0. You should accept a `String` instead. Here's the code corrected to do that

```
System.out.println("Please enter the new members birthday, in the format of DD/MM/YY:");
this.birthdate = console1.nextLine();
while(birthdate.length() != 6){
    System.out.println("Please give a valid date of birth in the format of: DD/MM/YY");
    this.birthdate = console1.nextLine();
}
```

This assumes that you changed the type of `birthdate` to `String`. You should know that your validation strategy is a naive one since anyone can enter a length 6 string without it being a valid birthdate or a birthdate at all. Use regular expressions as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15491894/12188799) for that kind of validations. Regular expressions can be applied to any string with the `String.matches()` method by passing to it the regular expression. A different approach would be to [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25458832/how-can-i-convert-an-integer-e-g-19000101-to-java-util-date) the integer into a date time object.